# Matplotlib - Change the white space between specific subplots in a grid grid

Tags: matplotlib, grid, whitespace, centering, axis-labels

I have a grid of subplots and I would like to adjust the white space between only two of them such that the shared x labels are centred without overlapping either graph.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61068411/how-to-center-shared-y-labels-for-two-horizontal-bar-plots) has a solution for when these are the only two subplots. However I'm struggling to adjust this to two specific subplots in a grid of many.

This code can be used to illustrate my problem.

```
In [1]
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15, 10))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2,4)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1:3])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 3])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 2])
ax7 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 3])


np.random.seed(19680801)

# Example data
people = ('Really Really Long Name', 'Another Long Name', 'Short Name', 'Name', 'N')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))

ax5.barh(y_pos, performance, align='center')
ax5.set_yticks(y_pos, labels=people)
ax5.invert_xaxis()
ax5.set_xlabel('Label')
ax5.set_title('Bar 1')

ax6.barh(y_pos, performance, align='center')
ax6.set_yticks(y_pos, labels=people)
ax6.set_xlabel('Label')
ax6.set_title('Bar 2')

Out [1]
```

[image]

If I apply the solution to the linked question here then every subplot's white space is effected. I know this is because it calls on `fig.dpi_scale_trans` which effects the whole figure but I'm new to transforms and can't work out what to use in its place

```
In [2]
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.7)

plt.setp(axes[0].yaxis.get_majorticklabels(), ha='center')

# Create offset transform by some points in x direction
dx = 60 / 72.
dy = 0 / 72.
offset = mlb.transforms.ScaledTranslation(dx, dy, fig.dpi_scale_trans)
# apply offset transform to all y ticklabels.
for label in ax6.yaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    label.set_transform(label.get_transform() + offset)

Out [2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this so posting my own answer in case anybody has a similar problem in the future.

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256492/subplot-specific-spacing-and-single-axis-label?rq=1) from 7 years ago contained the necessary help to solve the problem.

Essentially you must plot and position different GridSpecs in the figure using `GridSpec` from `matplotlib.gridspec` rather than calling one with `fig.add_gridspec()`

[Link to GridSpec documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html)

Following on from my example above I wanted to create a 2x4 grid. To do that we can plot the following grids in set positions of the figure:

```
Left: 1x2
Top Centre: 1x1
Bottom Centre: 2x1
Right: 1x2   


In [1]:
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15, 10))

# Example Data
people = ('Really Really Long Name', 'Another Long Name', 'Short Name', 'Name', 
'N')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))

# Left portion of grid (2x1). 
# 'left' and 'right' tell the grid where it should start and finish
gs1 = GridSpec(2, 1)
gs1.update(left = 0, right = 0.2)

# Plotting empty subplots for illustration purposes
for i in gs1:
    ax = plt.subplot(i)

# Mirroring on the right portion of the grid    
gs2 = GridSpec(2, 1)
gs2.update(left = 0.8, right = 1)
for i in gs2:
    ax = plt.subplot(i)
    
# Plotting in top center
# Note here we only need to plot a 1x1
gs3 = GridSpec(1, 1)
gs3.update(left = 0.25, right = 0.75, bottom = 0.53) #0.53 aligns with sides
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs3[0])

# Plotting the barh in the bottom center
# wsapce only adjusts this grid not the entire figure
gs4 = GridSpec(1, 2)
gs4.update(left = 0.2, right = 0.8, top = 0.45, wspace = 0.75) 


# Left barh
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs4[0])
ax5.barh(y_pos, performance, align='center')
ax5.set_yticks([])
ax5.invert_xaxis()
ax5.set_xlabel('Label')
ax5.set_title('Bar 1')

# Right barh
ax6 = plt.subplot(gs4[1])
ax6.barh(y_pos, performance, align='center')
ax6.set_yticks(y_pos, labels=people)
ax6.set_xlabel('Label')
ax6.set_title('Bar 2')



plt.show()

Out [1]:
```

[image]